# aligning,extracting images from listView1

Tags: c#, winforms

hi
i am using window.form application in c#.
I want to  form at run time according to screen resolution. It is working.
I have added listView1 that contains image prview at run time. I have put it inside groupbox and set property dock=left. Every thing is fine. 
Here are few short questions about that

1-
Now I have added a buton at bottom left of groupbox but it is not visible due to dock=left of group. What should i do??

2-
Contents(Images)  shown in listView1 are not centered. I have to scroll left to see the contents. How can i do it?

3-
I have added checkboxs in listView1 which are added (bydefault) to left hand side of images. Is there anyway to set it right hand side.

4-
How can i show the selected contents(checkbox) in picturebox /pictureboxes. 
thanx in advance
regards,
shahzad